# How can I align an image between two other blocks without affecting them?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am making a website to host my blog and artwork. I am trying to put the Twitter icon between the centered header and the very left of my screen. 
[Click here to see the top of the page that I'm referencing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u3od.png)

Here is the following code for the respective parts.

```
CSS: https://pastebin.com/mqQUqxs1

HTML: https://pastebin.com/GA2bqBXG
```

Comment: Put everything in a container div 
Make a new div with a width of 50% inside the container div with text-align: center;
put the twitter icon inside that inner div

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way but you could hack it using flexbox. You're gonna need empty span elements to make sure space is distributed how you want it to. Like this:

```css
header {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span></span>
  <div id="twitter">
    <a href="twitter.com/wisopco"><img src="img\twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="social"></a>
  </div>
  <h2 id="sultown" class="nav"> <a href="index.html"> SULTOWN </a></h1>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</header>
<form>
  <div id="search"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="explore"></div id="search">
</form>

<a href="blogs/spectroscopy.html"><img src="img\spectroscopy.png" alt="Spectroscopy" class="media"></a>
```

As I said, the `span`s are only place keepers for the spacing...

Comment: I have an image of the twitter icon. How can I do it with my provided code? I tried, and it got really messy...

Comment: What part of the code do you want in the header? Only the image and the title or the search form too?

Comment: There, if you have more questions about flex-box, I highly suggest looking at this css-tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I found a way of doing it somehow.